# What does this exception thrown while using htmlunit in a webservice mean?

Tags: java, html, web-services, webserver, htmlunit

I'm trying to use htmlunit in a web service. I created a dynamic web project and implemented the function homepage(). Then I used the web service wizard to generate the web server and the client. When I tried to use it, this exception is thrown.

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/FailingHttpStatusCodeException; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/FailingHttpStatusCodeException Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/FailingHttpStatusCodeException; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/FailingHttpStatusCodeException
```

I added the htmunit jars into the buildpath. There is no reason for it to be unable to locate the classes. The server class is below:

```
package test.eko;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class TestEko {

    public String homePage(String place, String checkinDate, String checkoutDate){
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);

    String URL = "http://hotels.travelcomparing.com/SearchResults.aspx?languageCode=EN&currencyCode=EUR&destination=place:" + place + "&radius=0km&checkin=" + checkinDate +"&checkout=" + checkoutDate + "&Rooms=1&adults_1=1&pageSize=15&pageIndex=0&sort=MinRate-asc&showSoldOut=false&view=hc_sr_summary&scroll=0&mapstate=contracted";

    HtmlPage page = null;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(URL);
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    String htmlContent = page.asXml();

        String hotelName = "";
        String priceFrom = "";

        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            int index1 = htmlContent.indexOf ( "<div fn=");
            int index2 = htmlContent.indexOf("<div fn=", index1 + 8);
            String row = (String) htmlContent.subSequence(index1 , index2);
            htmlContent = htmlContent.substring(index2);
            //System.out.println(row);

            int index3 = row.indexOf("class=\"hc_i_hotel\" p=\"2\">");
            int index4 = row.indexOf("</a>", index3);
            hotelName = (String) row.subSequence(index3 + 61, index4 -34);
            System.out.println(hotelName);
            result = result + hotelName + " ";

            int index5 = row.indexOf("<dd class=\"hc_i_price\">");
            int index6 = row.indexOf("</dd>", index5);
            String priceRow = (String) row.subSequence(index5, index6 + 5);

            int index7 = priceRow.indexOf("<span class=\"hc_pr_syb\">");
            int index8 = priceRow.indexOf("<span class=\"hc_pr_cur\">");
            priceFrom = (String) priceRow.subSequence(index7 + 148, index8 - 38);
            System.out.println(priceFrom);
            result = result + priceFrom + "    ";
        }
        return result;


}

}
```

This code should take 3 strings as parameters and access a website with those parameters and then save the page to a string and parse it for some information. Then it should return those information concatenated in a single string. The code worked normally in a normal project (not a dynamic web project). I'm very new to web services and I'm not sure what I did wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you add the jars to the generated war file? The container needs them to run just as much as the compiler to compile.

Comment: Well, since I don't really know what a war file is or where it is located, I'm pretty sure I didn't. Where can I find it? I looked around in the project explorer and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added the htmunit jars into the buildpath (...) The code worked normally in a normal project (not a dynamic web project)

When working on Dynamic Web Projects, all your third party libraries must be in the *WEB-INF/lib* folder in order to be recognized and loaded by the web application server. Make sure to do this, then re-build your application and try to deploy it, run your tests, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works. I need to ask two more things though; 1) Do you know any good tutorials that have those kind of information in it? 2) I don't know how to start the web service again after stopping the tomcat server. whenever I try to re-run a web service I get an error such as this: "HTTP Status 404 - /Hello/
type Status report

message /Hello/

description The requested resource is not available."

Comment: @user2297163 1) [WAR file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(Sun_file_format)), the last line of the article. 2) Web Services don't run by themselves like console applications, they run inside a Web Application Server. This means, you need your Tomcat (or another Java Web App Server like JBossor GlassFish) running and deploy your web service in order to be consumed.

Comment: That's the problem. When I stop the tomcat and then right click and select run as > run on server for the server project, the tomcat starts again, displays this as the last line in the console : May 21, 2013 3:07:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1855 ms          but it shows the 404 error on the generated client.

Comment: @user2297163 clean your Tomcat: remove the deployed app, restart it and re-deploy your app. It should work (it works for me atm).

Comment: I tried cleaning, removing the app, restarting and all but it still showed the 404 in the eclipse. but when I tried reaching it with my browser(chrome) It worked. it is ok for me to reach it that way atm, but I'd still like to know why it does that.

Comment: @user2297163 IMO do not trust in the eclipse internal browser, it will give you lot of headaches. Instead, use a real browser like Chrome or Firefox. Or even better, test your Web Services using [Web Service Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer/WebServiceExplorer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the replies and the answer. They really helped me in this project. I tried to implement another web service, this time using selenium, but I got a similar error. the link to the question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660742/using-selenium-in-a-web-service-throws-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-exception   if you have time and if you know about selenium can you please take a look at that one too. Thanks again for all your help.